# A curious identity for powers of the generating function of the Catalan numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

For a power series $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ let $\displaystyle[f(x)]_r=\sum_{n\geq r} a_n x^n.$

Let $\displaystyle c(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ be the generating function of the Catalan numbers which satisfies $c(x)=1+xc(x)^2.$
Computations suggest that
$$\sum_{j=r}^{2m}\left(\binom{2m}{j}-\binom{2m}{2r-j-1}\right)x^j c(x)^{2j+1-2r}=\left[c(x)^{2m+1-2r}\right]_r.$$
For $r=0$ this reduces to the trivial identity $c(x)^{2m+1}=c(x)\left(1+x c(x)^2\right)^{2m}.$

Any idea how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea that seems promising but didn't quite work out the way I expected; maybe there will be something of use in it?  The basic strategy is that, since you know what you want when $r = 0$, it would be enough to show that $f(m + 1, r + 1) - f(m, r)$ has the correct value (and I choose this particular change in inputs to keep the difference in the right sides $[c^{2m + 1 - 2r}]_r$ tame).  So here goes (apologies in advance for the horrendously large formulas):

Let $\displaystyle f(m, r) := \sum_{j=r}^{2m}\left(\binom{2m}{j}-\binom{2m}{2r-j-1}\right)x^j c(x)^{2j+1-2r}$.  Since $x c^2 = c - 1$, we can rewrite this as $$f(m, r) = \sum_{j=r}^{2m}\left(\binom{2m}{j}-\binom{2m}{2r-j-1}\right)(c - 1)^j c^{1-2r}.$$  Now let's consider $f(m + 1, r + 1)$; by definition, we have \begin{align*} c^{2r + 1} f(m + 1, r + 1) & = \sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m + 2}{j}-\binom{2m + 2}{2r-j + 1}\right)(c - 1)^j \\
& = \sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m}{j} + 2\binom{2m}{j - 1} + \binom{2m}{j - 2} -\binom{2m}{2r-j + 1} - 2 \binom{2m}{2r - j} - \binom{2m}{2r - j - 1} \right)(c - 1)^j 
\\
& = \sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m}{j - 2} -\binom{2m}{2r-j + 1}  \right)(c - 1)^j 
+2\sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m}{j - 1} - \binom{2m}{2r-j}\right)(c - 1)^j 
+\sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m}{j} -\binom{2m}{2r-j - 1}\right)(c - 1)^j \\
& = \sum_{j=r - 1}^{2m}\left(\binom{2m}{j} -\binom{2m}{2r-j - 1}  \right)(c - 1)^{j + 2} 
+2\sum_{j=r}^{2m + 1}\left(\binom{2m}{j} - \binom{2m}{2r-j - 1}\right)(c - 1)^{j + 1} 
+\sum_{j=r + 1}^{2m + 2}\left(\binom{2m}{j} -\binom{2m}{2r-j - 1}\right)(c - 1)^j.\end{align*}
In the last expression, the first sum is $c^{2r - 1}(c - 1)^2 \left(f(m, r) + \left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right)(c - 1)^{r - 1}\right)$, the second sum is $2c^{2r - 1}(c - 1)f(m, r)$ and the third sum is $c^{2r - 1} \left( f(m, r) - \left(\binom{2m}{r} - \binom{2m}{r - 1}\right)(c - 1)^r\right)$.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
c^{2r + 1} f(m + 1, r + 1)& = c^{2r - 1}\left(\left((c - 1)^2 + 2(c - 1) + 1\right)f(m, r) + \left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right)(c - 1)^{r + 1} - \left(\binom{2m}{r} - \binom{2m}{r - 1}\right)(c - 1)^r\right) \\
& = c^{2r + 1} f(m, r)+ c^{2r - 1}(c - 1)^r\left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right)((c - 1) + 1)\end{align*}
and therefore
$$f(m + 1, r + 1) - f(m, r) = c^{-1}(c - 1)^r\left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right).$$ Now I was hoping to get something that was obviously just a single monomial in $x$, which obviously this is not.  But maybe it's just a small error somewhere?

Comment: After correcting a typo this gives the correct result
$f(m + 1, r + 1) - f(m, r) = c^{-2r}(c - 1)^r\left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right)= \left(\binom{2m}{r - 1} - \binom{2m}{r}\right)x^r.$

Comment: @JohannCigler Ok great!